# determine true mail sent status (PHP mail())

Tags: php, sendmail, lamp

I am using inbuilt support of sending mails in php.

```
$status=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f $from");
```

I am on LAMP server and we use sendmail Unix utility. php mail() returns true status if it has handed over the mail to sendmail so we can not be sure that whether a mail has been sent successfully of not. Now what I want is to make some socket connection between php and sendmail so that I can get the "True status" whether mail has been sent or not.

I am very new for PHP. This is the part of the first problem which I am solving in PHP. I Goggled but I am not getting exactly how to proceed further. Guide me how can I get true status whether a mail has been sent or not at PHP end?

Comment: i grep the mail log files, if i need this. not practical to do this 'live' as mail can be queued for some time

Comment: @Dagon- So You are saying first know which log sendmail configured to write. then grep the log in a typical busy system it may be huge. then get the status.I don't this its good idea. Can there be something else? is this the only option.

Comment: depending on the mail server there may be command line options

Comment: "This is the part of the first problem which I am solving in PHP." perhaps if you shared the whole thing alternatives could be suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Socket connection: [read the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), then write a *standards-compliant* SMTP client program. [don't even bother unless you want to throw a few weeks of your life away]

**Option 2:** Use [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or one of the other bazillion mailing libraries that have already written a standards-compliant SMTP client that will *actually* tell you if the mail was successfully sent or not.

Comment: what functions of PHPmailer  are you referring to ??

Comment: @Dagon the bit where you can simply point it at a smarthost [eg: localhost w/sendmail running] and it submits via SMTP rather than just dropping it directly into the queue.

Comment: sending it via a socket connection to smtp will still lead to the email being queued, and provide no more information on 'sent status'

Comment: A. The vast majority of MTAs will perform basic validation during the SMTP submission process. B. Most MTAs perform the remote delivery in-step with the local SMTP submission and can pass message status back to the client. C. Literally *anything* is better than the true/false return that `mail()` gives back.

Comment: please provide the code, using PHPmailer, that will report back the 'true sent status'. i would use it in a flash, if i believed you :-)

Comment: @Dagon https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1152-L1219

Comment: ok but my mail is being queued so the responses and requests, cant be happening in real time ?

Comment: @dagon not necessarily. Like I said, an MTA can deliver the mail as you're submitting it. It would only be queued locally if the remote MTA returned a deferral or was unreachable. Modern MTAs are very smart. Regardless, the MTA will generally apply stricter checks on message parameters during SMTP submission, ie. validating the sendign/receiving domains, checking if you are allowed to relay remotely, etc, and you can get a *meaningful* error response in-program instead of having to dig through the logs.

Answer (score 3):

It won't get you anywhere if you check that your local sendmail demon has received the mail. The important part would be that sendmail was able to forward the mail to another mail server.

But this really is also only half of the truth, because that server need not be the final destination of the mail. So after the mail left your sendmail demon, you cannot say anything about whether or not the mail reached it's destination or not.

If you need to be sure, do the obvious thing: Include a link in the mail that needs to be clicked.

Otherwise, assume your local sendmail is working (probably monitor if it really is), and simply send the mail.

Comment: Also, setting a `Return-Path:` header in the email to a mailbox that gets checked for bounces will help weed out invalid/defunct email addresses.